# find the derivative of order 2001 of $\frac{x^{5}}{x^{6}+1}$ at 0

Tags: calculus

I know that $\frac{x^{5}}{x^{6}+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}x^{6n+5}$

I tried to differentiate this sum, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you asking the 2,001st derivative **at 0**?

Comment: Whay is the 2001st derivative of $x^{6n+5}$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: What is the coefficient at $x^{2001}$?

We know that for $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n$
$$
c_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.
$$